# Persistence xml in tests

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa-2.0

In my spring JPa app..

I recently got into a bit of an issue whereby i had to add the following in the persistence xml to enable my tests to work:

```
<class>com....</class>
<class>com....</class>
```

what i found odd, was that it worked fine if i placed a bare bones persistence xml in main resources.. and my tests would pick it up.

But it refused to pick up the bare bones persistence xml from my tests resources.

Anyone shed any light why this is

Answer (score 0):

Is your test resources folder in your classpath?

Comment: yes it is in my classpath, it works fine as long as my test persistence xml contains the the classes properties. While if i leave it in the main/resources i dont need to specify the class property. I like to know why.

Comment: I am afraid you might want to provide the entire XML and provide more details on your issue. I am unable to see what you are trying to do